# How can I integrate cimgui with GLFW and Vulkan into a zig project?

Tags: imgui, zig

I'm trying to use GLFW with Vulkan and cimgui. GLFW and Vulkan and being included and linked fine (there were no issues before I included cimgui). I include all of the C into my project like so:

```
const c = @cImport({
    // C Imgui
    @cDefine("CIMGUI_DEFINE_ENUMS_AND_STRUCTS", {});
    @cInclude("cimgui.h");
    @cInclude("cimgui_impl.h");

    // GLFW and Vulkan
    @cDefine("GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE", {});
    @cDefine("GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN", {});
    @cInclude("GLFW/glfw3.h");
    @cInclude("vulkan/vulkan.h");
});
```

Then, when I create a variable to store window data:

```
var main_window_data: c.ImGui_ImplVulkanH_Window = null;
```

I get this error:

```
src/application.zig:25:24: error: root struct of file '.home.naninoni.src.ray_tracer.zig-cache.o.e4d475f56697871ff2702a77a0125b18.cimport' has no member named 'ImGui_ImplVulkanH_Window'
var main_window_data: c.ImGui_ImplVulkanH_Window = null;
```

In my `build.zig`, I'm compiling the C++ sources like so:

```
const IMGUI_SOURCES = [_][]const u8 {
    "deps/cimgui/cimgui.cpp",

    "deps/cimgui/imgui/imgui_demo.cpp",
    "deps/cimgui/imgui/imgui_draw.cpp",
    "deps/cimgui/imgui/imgui_tables.cpp",
    "deps/cimgui/imgui/imgui.cpp",
    "deps/cimgui/imgui/imgui_widgets.cpp",
};

exe.linkLibC();
exe.linkSystemLibrary("glfw");
exe.linkSystemLibrary("Vulkan");

exe.linkLibCpp();    
exe.addIncludePath("deps/cimgui");
exe.addIncludePath("deps/cimgui/imgui");
exe.addIncludePath("deps/cimgui/imgui/backends");
exe.addIncludePath("deps/cimgui/generator/output");
exe.addCSourceFiles(&IMGUI_SOURCES, &.{});
```

I tried including `imgui_impl_vulkan.h` and `imgui_impl_glfw.h`, but then I got a million errors like these:

```
error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    constexpr ImVec4()                                        : x(0.0f), y(0.0f), z(0.0f), w(0.0f) { }
```

I also tried including `imgui_impl_vulkan.h` and `imgui_impl_glfw.h` instead of `cimgui_impl.h`, but the same thing happened. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

**[ORIGINAL ANSWER]**

Maybe I am coming too late, but I found a solution so the next guy falling on this topic will not waste time as much as I wasted mine.

First of all, you should generate the backends you need with the `cimgui` generator:

```bash
$ cd deps/cimgui/generator        # The cimgui generator works 
                                  # only in its directory.
$ ./generator.sh -c "glfw vulkan" # Please, pay attention to the 
                                  # doubles quotes.
```

Later you should delegate this job to your `build.zig`.

Then add these lines to your `@cImport`:

```c
const c = @cImport({
    // C Imgui
    @cDefine("CIMGUI_DEFINE_ENUMS_AND_STRUCTS", {});

    // These lines:
    @cDefine("CIMGUI_USE_GLFW", {});
    @cDefine("CIMGUI_USE_VULKAN", {});

    @cInclude("cimgui.h");
    @cInclude("cimgui_impl.h");

    // ! \\ WARNING: // ! \\
    // Maybe you should move these following lines before cImgui
    // @cIncludes and @cDefine, because Imgui depends on for 
    // its backends.
    // GLFW and Vulkan:
    @cDefine("GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE", {});
    @cDefine("GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN", {});
    @cInclude("GLFW/glfw3.h");
    @cInclude("vulkan/vulkan.h");
});
```

Finally you should add these lines in your `build.zig`:

```c
const IMGUI_SOURCES = [_][]const u8 {
    "deps/cimgui/cimgui.cpp",
    "deps/cimgui/imgui/imgui_demo.cpp",
    "deps/cimgui/imgui/imgui_draw.cpp",
    "deps/cimgui/imgui/imgui_tables.cpp",
    "deps/cimgui/imgui/imgui.cpp",
    "deps/cimgui/imgui/imgui_widgets.cpp",

    // These lines:
    "deps/cimgui/imgui/backends/imgui_impl_glfw.cpp",
    "deps/cimgui/imgui/backends/imgui_impl_vulkan.cpp",
};
```

---

**[EDIT] - 23/07/2023**

Unfortunately, with this changes, your program will go further but you will encounter a new error for each `Imgui_Impl*` you are using that looks like this:

```c
error: ld.lld: undefined symbol: ImGui_ImplVulkan_Init
    note: referenced by your_file.zig:102 (/path/to/your/zig/file/your_file.zig:102)
    note:               /path/to/your/project/zig-cache/o/289b11a03ec527342c42c8f0bd4fd76e/your_project.o:(your.function.using.ImGui_ImplVulkan_Init)
    note: did you mean to declare ImGui_ImplVulkan_Init(ImGui_ImplVulkan_InitInfo*, VkRenderPass_T*) as extern "C"?
    note: defined in: /path/to/your/project/zig-cache/o/34e4e97a5b4f3b2c1930a506bfa38f32/imgui_impl_vulkan.o
```

You have to make those new modifications to allow your program to compile:

- Reduce your `@cImport` as follow:

```c
const c = @cImport({
    // C Imgui
    @cDefine("CIMGUI_DEFINE_ENUMS_AND_STRUCTS", {})
    @cInclude("cimgui.h");

    @cDefine("GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE", {});
    @cDefine("GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN", {});
    @cInclude("GLFW/glfw3.h");
    @cInclude("vulkan/vulkan.h");
});
```

- Keep the modifications I described in my original answer into your `build.zig`, but remove this line from your original file:

```c
exe.addIncludePath("deps/cimgui/generator/output");
```

### Into `deps/cimgui/cimgui.cpp`:

- Add these includes at the end of the file:

```c
#include "imgui/backends/imgui_impl_glfw.h"
#include "imgui/backends/imgui_impl_vulkan.h"
```

- After the includes you just added, for each `Imgui_Impl*` you are using and you can find into `deps/cimgui/generator/output/cimgui_impl.h` (that you generate as I described in my original answer), add a new binding function. So for example for `CIMGUI_API bool ImGui_ImplVulkan_Init(ImGui_ImplVulkan_InitInfo* info,VkRenderPass render_pass)`, add this function at the end of the file (pay attention to the `ig` I added before the name of the binding function. You can change it (or change the entire name) by whatever you want but **do not use the same function name defined by the backends you want to use**):

```c
CIMGUI_API bool igImGui_ImplVulkan_Init(ImGui_ImplVulkan_InitInfo* info,VkRenderPass render_pass)
{
    return ImGui_ImplVulkan_Init(info,render_pass);
}
```

### Into `deps/cimgui/cimgui.h`:

- copy the `deps/cimgui/generator/output/cimgui_impl.h` content **before** the very last `#endif`,
- remove `#ifdef CIMGUI_USE_VULKAN` and `#ifdef CIMGUI_USE_GLFW` and their matching `#endif` that you recently pasted from `deps/cimgui/generator/output/cimgui_impl.h`,
- remove the `struct` declarations from what you recently added. For example, keep this: `typedef struct ImGui_ImplVulkanH_Frame ImGui_ImplVulkanH_FrameSemaphores;` or this: `struct ImGui_ImplVulkanH_FrameSemaphores;` but remove this:

```c
struct ImGui_ImplVulkanH_FrameSemaphores
{
    VkSemaphore ImageAcquiredSemaphore;
    VkSemaphore RenderCompleteSemaphore;
};
```

- add those extra macros before the `deps/cimgui/generator/output/cimgui_impl.h` you freshly pasted:

```c
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>
```